# Division in Python gives 0

Tags: python

I keep getting 0 if I simply divide in python. Is there any way that we get get a solution? I even tried doubleslash, same result.

The following is the code:

```
print(5/10)

0
```

Comment: You should upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: In Python 2, `/` between two `int` objects is always equivalent to `//` in Python 3. You'd have to use a `float` object to get full division. Probably, you should just use Python 3, since Python 2 is no longer supported (and over a decade out of date...)